# Proguard keepclassmembers keeps class

Tags: java, annotations, proguard

Sorry if I've missed a response that would cover this, but I've tried to be diligent about finding anything similar.

I'm really confused by Proguard's behaviour, and I'm wondering if I'm reading the docs wrong or if the behaviour is wrong.

I want to retain annotated fields and members in a class, if that class is kept.  So I used `keepclassmembers` like so:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.** {
    @com.mycompany.**
    public com.mycompany.** *;
    @com.mycompany.**
    public void *(com.mycompany.**);
}
```

(This configuration was built by the GUI, but I think I see what it's doing.)  The Proguard docs say

> -keepclassmembers *[,modifier,...] class_specification*
>
> Specifies class members to be preserved, if their classes are preserved as well. For  example, you may want to keep all serialization fields and methods of classes that implement the Serializable interface.

Sounds good.  But I'm getting classes I don't expect in the output, just because they have @annotated listeners.  `-whyareyoukeeping class com.company.MyServiceImpl`?

```
com.mycompany.MyServiceImpl
  is invoked by    com.mycompany.MyServiceImpl: void handleEvent(com.mycompany.MyEvent) (34:35)
  is kept by a directive in the configuration.
```

`handleEvent` just calls another method in `MyServiceImpl`, **so it doesn't seem to be a valid reason to keep the whole class**, but that's the only think I can think of.

Why does `keepclassmembers` appear to force `keep` on any class containing a specified member, not only "if their classes are preserved as well"?  But more directly, **how can I keep public annotated event listeners in classes that Proguard is already keeping via other rules?**

Comment: I ended up with something workable as follows.
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class com.mycompany.** { @com.mycompany.** <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation class com.mycompany.** { @com.mycompany.** <methods>; }

I think the "allow" modifiers were the magic sauce, but that combination is baffling -- seems like it undoes the whole directive.

Hope this gives somebody some ideas in the future that might save them a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial configuration and interpretation of it look correct. It also works if I try it on a simple example: annotated fields and methods are kept if their classes are already kept. Of course, those annotated methods may contain code that drags in more classes.

The output of -whyareyoukeeping only tells half the story and isn't very helpful in this case. You could check if -printseeds provides some hints.

The workable configuration with 'allow' modifiers doesn't seem to make much sense; I wouldn't trust it too much.

If you still think there is a bug, you can report it in the [ProGuard bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=54750&atid=474704), preferably with an example that allows me to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The "working" configuration I posted as a comment eventually resulted in other issues.  I appreciate the sanity check.  Eventually I just backed off on the optimization step.  I'll have the chance to revisit this later and I'll certainly report anything where there's a sane reproduction recipe.